# Nesting and using LIKE and OR in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to nest this query, but I am getting the error: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "%malfunction%".

```
select *
from (
select column_one, column_two
from table
group by column_one, column_two
) as new_table
where column_two like '%false%' or '%malfunction%' or '%accidental%' or '%mistaken%'
order by column_one
```

Column_two is not boolean but it's identifying it as one.
I feel like I'm missing something small, but I can't find it. Help!

Comment: You must put the column name on each condition: `where column_two like '%false%' or column_two like '%malfunction%' or column_two like '%accidental%' or column_two like '%mistaken%'`

Comment: I knew I wasn't thinking correctly. This was exactly what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help @Dave

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any(array[...])`, example:

```
with test (col) as (
    values
    ('pear'), ('banana'), ('apple')
)

select *
from test
where col like any(array['%ea%', '%ba%']);

  col   
--------
 pear
 banana
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is something like select col1, col2, 
from table_name
where condition1 OR condition2 OR condition3 ...;